# UnityEngine.Videoplayer not rendering video on IOS Devices

Tags: android, ios, iphone, unity-game-engine, video-player

I am using unity's video player to render a video in the scene,

1. I spawn the video in the scene dynamically, (Render Mode: Camera Far Plane)
2. Let it play on awake
3. And Assign its texture on to a raw image in the canvas (So, it plays on the raw image).

It works great on Android Devices and renders perfectly, but for some reason, it does not work on IOS Devices. The Video Does play (I can hear the audio), but it does not render in scene for some reason. I have no clue what possibly can be the reason for this? I suspected Render Texture to be the issue but I tested it individually by rendering a camera onto it and it worked fine when I tested it on IOS. So, That narrow's down to VIdeoPlayer being the culprit only.

Can Anyone please help me figure out what the issue could be?

Comment: Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was, H264 and H265 Codecs are not supported for some reasons in IOS, You have to convert all your videos to VP8 Codec in unity, and it will render fine in ios devices.
[image: Change this codec on your video in unity]

And Voila, it should work fine now.